# Python Pandas Complex Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
     Name    Status    Date

1    Joe     In    1/2/2003
2    Pete    Out   1/2/2003
3    Mary    In    1/2/2003
• • •
4    Joe     In    3/4/2004
5    Pete    In    3/5/2004
6    Mary    Out   4/8/2004
```

If I do the following group-by action :

```
df.groupby(["Name", "Status"]).last()
```

I get the following:

```
Joe    In    3/4/2004
Pete   In    3/5/2004
       Out   1/2/2003
Mary   In    1/2/2003
       Out   4/8/2004
```

Notice that Joe has no "out" grouping results because there are no "out" values for Joe in the dataframe.

I want to be able to select people from the dataframe or the subsequent groupby who have only "In" status or only "out" status across a date range from people as opposed to people who have both "in"s AND "outs" across a particular date range. I'm stumped as to how to approach this. I could proceed if the groupby result gave me something like:

```
Joe    Out   np. Nan
```

But it doesn't.

oh, I do the groupby last because I need to get the last date where people leave both "In" and "out " status like Pete and Mary. But I need to treat Joe - who only has " in" status and no "out" status for the period - differently.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Not sure what solution you propose

Comment: I need 3 dataframes that look like the result of the groupby with the last date for each grouped status. In one dataframe names with only "in"s . In one data frame names with only "outs" . In the third dataframe names with both "in"s and "outs". Each data frame should have the status (group) and the last date.  So in my group by above , Joe would be in one dataframe, Pete and Mary in a second datafrarne, and there would he no third frame because there are no names with only "out" status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want. But you can try reindexing

From

```
x = df.groupby(['Name', 'Status']).last()


Date
Name    Status  
Joe     In  3/4/2004
Mary    In  1/2/2003
        Out 4/8/2004
Pete    In  3/5/2004
        Out 1/2/2003
```

You can make it

```
size = x.index.levels[0].size
f = np.repeat(np.arange(size), 2)
s = [0,1] * size

x.reindex(pd.MultiIndex(levels=x.index.levels, labels=[f, s]))

                 Date
Name    Status  
Joe     In       3/4/2004
        Out      NaN
Mary    In       1/2/2003
        Out      4/8/2004
Pete    In       3/5/2004
        Out      1/2/2003
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Can you explain the solution a bit more please? I don't understand the syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Windstorm. So, you have a `MultiIndex` data frame after the groupby right? What I did was to create a new `MultiIndex` and make `x` follow this multi index.  A `MultiIndex` has levels and values, and I created them such that all `level=0` and `level=1` followed the template `[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,....]` and `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1....]` respectively.That way, every `Name` would have two rows (because the first list has two of each number) and every `Status` would have one `In` and one `Out` (because `[0,1,0,1]`) etc.Not sure this is the simplest way, but its what came to mind when trying thesoluti

Comment: Thanks for explaining Rafael . I will digest your explanation and come back with follow up if necessary!